# How can i change the value of an array then display the whole new array?

Tags: c++, arrays

i need help. I have an array of 10, and it consists of a string and a value initialized to it. My question is how i can ask the user to input how much more to add or how much to remove. then display the updated list.
for example choose valve, then add 2 more, which will make it 12, then display the updated array with the other arrays. i need to pass it through a function also. please and thank you for the help in advance, here it my code so far. Feel free to criticize as much as you guys would like. It will only help me get better :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//define Structure as invParts
struct invParts{

string name;
int qty;


};


void addparts(invParts *&c,int);
void removeparts(invParts *&c, int);




int main()
{
invParts *descrip;
int row = 0;
char choice;


invParts bin[10]= { {"valve",10}, {"Bearing",5}, {"Bushing",21},
                     {"Coupling",7}, {"Flange",5}, {"Gear",5}, 
                     {"Gear House", 5}, {"Vacuum         Gripper", 25}, 
                     {"Cable",18}, {"Rod",12}, };



cout<<"-----------------------------------------------------" << endl;
cout<<"Part Description" << "      " << "Number of parts in the bin" << endl;
cout <<"----------------------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << endl;
for(row = 0; row < 10; row++)
{
    cout << setw(11)<< left <<bin[row].name << setw(25) << right << bin[row].qty<< endl;



}
cout << endl;
cout << "Here are 3 options" << endl;
cout << "Type A , to Add parts" << endl;
cout << "Type R , to Remove parts" << endl;
cout << "Type E, to Exit Program" << endl;
cout << "Choose your option: "; 
cin >> choice;
cout << endl;
switch (choice)
{
int num;
case 'A' :
case 'a' :  cout <<"You will now add" << endl;
            addparts(descrip,num);
            break;

case 'R':
case 'r': cout <<"You will now remove" << endl;
          //removeparts(descrip,num);

             break;
case 'E':
case 'e': cout<<"Now exiting program" << endl;
            exit(0);




}






system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

```
void addparts(invParts *&c,int number)
{
    string what;
    int n;


    cout <<"Which part? " << endl;
    cin >> what;


         //am i doing this right?

    if ( what == "valve" || what == "Valve")
        cout <<"How much do you want to add? "<<endl;
        cin >> n;



}
/*void removeparts(invParts *&c, int)
{

//you guys can show me how to do the add, i can do the remove


}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong data structure to capture the inventory. You need something like

```
typedef std::map<std::string, int> Inventory;
```

Here's an updated version of your program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef std::map<std::string, int> Inventory;

void initializeInventory(Inventory& inv);
void displayInventory(Inventory const& inv);
void addparts(Inventory& inv);
void removeparts(Inventory& inv);


int main()
{
   Inventory inv;
   char choice;

   initializeInventory(inv);

   displayInventory(inv);

   while ( true )
   {
      cout << "Here are 3 options" << endl;
      cout << "Type A , to Add parts" << endl;
      cout << "Type R , to Remove parts" << endl;
      cout << "Type E, to Exit Program" << endl;
      cout << "Choose your option: "; 
      cin >> choice;
      cout << endl;
      switch (choice)
      {
         case 'A' :
         case 'a' :  cout <<"You will now add" << endl;
                     addparts(inv);
                     break;

         case 'R':
         case 'r': cout <<"You will now remove" << endl;
                   //removeparts(inv);

                   break;
         case 'E':
         case 'e': cout<<"Now exiting program" << endl;
                   exit(0);
      }

      displayInventory(inv);
   }

   return 0;
}

void initializeInventory(Inventory& inv)
{
   inv["Valve"] = 10;
   inv["Bearing"] = 5;
   inv["Bushing"] = 21;
   inv["Coupling"] = 7;
   inv["Flange"] = 5;
   inv["Gear"] = 5; 
   inv["Gear House"] =  5;
   inv["Vacuum Gripper"] =  25;
   inv["Cable"] = 18;
   inv["Rod"] = 12;
}

void displayInventory(Inventory const& inv)
{
   cout<<"-----------------------------------------------------" << endl;
   cout<<"Part Description" << "      " << "Number of parts in the bin" << endl;
   cout <<"----------------------------------------------------" << endl;
   cout << endl;

   for (auto item : inv )
   {
      cout << setw(15) << left << item.first << setw(25) << right << item.second << endl;
   }

   cout << endl;
}

void addparts(Inventory& inv)
{
   string what;
   int n;

   cout <<"Which part? " << endl;
   cin >> what;


   //am i doing this right?
   Inventory::iterator iter = inv.find(what);
   if ( iter == inv.end() )
   {
      cout << "There is no such part in the inventory.\n";
      return;
   }

   cout <<"How much do you want to add? "<<endl;
   cin >> n;

   iter->second += n;
}

void removeparts(Inventory& inv)
{
   // ????
}
```

**Update**

The inventory can be initialized using:

```
Inventory inv = { {"Valve",10}, {"Bearing",5}, {"Bushing",21},
                  {"Coupling",7}, {"Flange",5}, {"Gear",5}, 
                  {"Gear House", 5}, {"Vacuum Gripper", 25}, 
                  {"Cable",18}, {"Rod",12} };
```

There is no need for a separate function to initialize the inventory.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, true. I was in a "divide the functionality into functions" mode.

Comment: @deckonsoul, it works for me using the flag `-std=c++11` with g++ 4.8.2. I also have it working at http://ideone.com/YhtrOV using c++14.